# Change values in new autoincrement field added to table from 0 to a meaningful number

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

After adding an autoincrement field to a table to act as a primary key, all records contain a 0 value in this field, so it is not much use for its intended purpose.

New records will get a good value, but what about the 3000+ entries with 0? Is there a way to alter those?

TIA!

Comment: strange, you can't have a primary key with same value...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you created the column. Can you post your code? And what engine are you using: MyISAM, InnoDB, or something else?

For example, I did a test with a table:

```
alter table test1 add column i int auto_increment primary key;
select i from test1;

+---+
| i |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
+---+
```

So in normal circumstances you get the values populated for existing records.